# Java - Force a class implementing an interface to declare an annotation

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I'm trying to force class SomeImpl to declare an annotation @SomeAnnotation if it is implementing interface SomeInterface. Solution can modify SomeInterface declaration.

```
public interface SomeInterface {}

public class SomeImpl implements SomeInterface -> compilation error

@SomeAnnotation
public class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface -> compilation ok
```

Use case: I'm using objects implementing SomeInterface in a method (not written by me, it's an external library) that always read the annotation @SomeAnnotation and it can not be empty or default.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to do this because...

Comment: What's the usecase? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Use case: I'm using objects implementing SomeInterface in a method (not written by me, it's an external library) that always read the annotation @SomeAnnotation and it can not be empty or default. I put it in the question now.

Comment: So write a code analysis tool to scan your code for that combination. Java itself cannot enforce you're constraint.

Comment: Write proper tests, that's the only way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems this can only be done using annotations processor (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).